# Multiple row insert from multiple row of data laravel livewire

Tags: laravel, associative-array, laravel-livewire

I have a table. In every cell of every columns of every rows there is an input tag.
My goal is To validate and insert all of this data at a single click.

```
<tbody>
@for($i=0; $i < $no; $i++)
    <tr>
        <td class="border w-2">{{($i+1)}}</td>
        <td class="border">
            <div class="flex">
                <x-jet-label for="name" class="text-xl" value="{{ __('Name') }}" />
                <x-jet-input id="name" class="block mt-1" type="text" wire:model="name" required />
            </div>
            @error('name') <span class="text-red-500">{{ $message }}</span>@enderror
            <div class="flex">
                <x-jet-label for="description" class="text-xl" value="{{ __('Description') }}" />
                <x-jet-input id="description" class=" mt-1" type="text" wire:model="description" required />
            </div>
            @error('description') <span class="text-red-500">{{ $message }}</span>@enderror
            <div class="flex">
                <x-jet-label for="code" class="text-xl" value="{{ __('Code') }}" />
                <x-jet-input id="code" class="block mt-1" type="text" wire:model="code" required />
            </div>
            @error('code') <span class="text-red-500">{{ $message }}</span>@enderror
        </td>
        <td class="border">
            <x-jet-input id="name" class=" mt-1" type="text" wire:model="name" required />
            @error('name') <span class="text-red-500">{{ $message }}</span>@enderror
        </td>
        <td class="border">
            <x-jet-input id="name" class=" mt-1" type="text" wire:model="name" required />
            @error('name') <span class="text-red-500">{{ $message }}</span>@enderror
        </td>
        <td class="border">
            <x-jet-input id="name" class=" mt-1" type="text" wire:model="name" required />
            @error('name') <span class="text-red-500">{{ $message }}</span>@enderror
        </td>
        <td class="border">
            <x-jet-input id="name" class=" mt-1" type="text" wire:model="name" required />
            @error('name') <span class="text-red-500">{{ $message }}</span>@enderror
        </td>
    </tr>
@endfor
</tbody>
```

Can someone help me? how can I create a model for an array of names[], description[], code[], image[], etc..

I want to know how to make a model that i can put `<x-jet-input type="text" wire:model="here" required />`

Comment: You can add Index to each wire model and add a parent array for all columns of the form.

Comment: well. i didn't use form. i just bind it to a model in a Livewire Class. i just had trouble binding it with an array model.

Comment: it would be easier if i use form.. but i did not.

Answer (score 0):

This really helped a lot.
[Data Binding][1]

and so I did this.

```
<tbody>
    <?php $color=1; ?>
    @for($i=0; $i < $no; $i++)
        <tr @if($color==1) class="bg-green-100 border-b-4" @else class="bg-red-100 border-b-4" @endif>
            <td class="border w-2 text-xl">{{($i+1)}}.</td>
            <td class="border">
                <div class="flex">
                    <x-jet-label for="items.{{$i}}.name" class="text-lg" value="{{ __('Name') }}" />
                    <x-jet-input id="items.{{$i}}.name" class="block mt-1" type="text" wire:model="items.{{$i}}.name" required />
                </div>
                @error('items.'.$i.'.name') <span class="text-red-500">{{ $message }}</span>@enderror
                <div class="flex">
                    <x-jet-label for="items.{{$i}}.description" class="text-lg" value="{{ __('Description') }}" />
                    <x-jet-input id="items.{{$i}}.description" class=" mt-1" type="text" wire:model="items.{{$i}}.description" required />
                </div>
                @error('description') <span class="text-red-500">{{ $message }}</span>@enderror
                <div class="flex">
                    <x-jet-label for="items.{{$i}}.code" class="text-lg" value="{{ __('Code') }}" />
                    <x-jet-input id="items.{{$i}}.code" class="block mt-1" type="text" wire:model="items.{{$i}}.code" required />
                </div>
                @error('code') <span class="text-red-500">{{ $message }}</span>@enderror
            </td>
            <td class="border">
                <x-jet-input id="items.{{$i}}.name" class=" mt-1" type="text" wire:model="items.{{$i}}.image" required />
                @error('name') <span class="text-red-500">{{ $message }}</span>@enderror
            </td>
            <td class="border">
                <x-jet-input id="items.{{$i}}.name" class=" mt-1" type="text" wire:model="items.{{$i}}.unit" required />
                @error('name') <span class="text-red-500">{{ $message }}</span>@enderror
            </td>
            <td class="border">
                <x-jet-input id="name" class=" mt-1" type="text" wire:model="items.{{$i}}.unitcost" required />
                @error('name') <span class="text-red-500">{{ $message }}</span>@enderror
            </td>
            <td class="border">
                <x-jet-input id="name" class=" mt-1" type="text" wire:model="items.{{$i}}.category" required />
                @error('name') <span class="text-red-500">{{ $message }}</span>@enderror
            </td>
        </tr>
        <?php $color==1 ? $color=2 : $color=1; ?>
    @endfor
    </tbody>
```